# Is it a must you get a visiting invitation letter from family related person in Canada?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, international-travel, visit

Can a friend invite you to Canada for a vist or is just a family member who can Invite you? If yes a friend can Invite you for a visit to Canada how can you proof you have ties with him/her

Answer (score 0):

> Can a friend invite you to Canada for a vist or is just a family member who can Invite you?

Any Canadian citizen or even a permanent resident can invite you to Canada.

> ...how can you proof you have ties with him/her

The person writing the letter must clarify the relationship they have to you. If the relationship can be evidenced by some documents, perfect. Include them as well. If not (friendship typically can't be evidenced by legal documents), it's not a showstopper. It's always up to the CIC to decide about your visa, whether you include a letter of invitation or not.

Source: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/letter-invitation.html